# Generic makefile for lyx

Tags: lyx, makefile

I have got a folder with many lyx files. What makefile will automatically build abc.pdf from abc.lyx? I would prefer a pattern so that I can address each pdf target separately. I have not found a working example online.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "address each pdf target separately". Do you mean run a different LyX command for each? Or run different commands in addition?

Comment: As far as I know, you define rules that depend on the file extension. Like, for each .lyx file there exists a corresponding .pdf target. By "address each pdf target separately" I just avoiding bash for-each loops that could do the job similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete Makefile:

```
abc.pdf: abc.lyx

.SUFFIXES: .lyx .pdf
# if lyx command fails, remove pdf
.lyx.pdf:
    lyx -e pdf4 "$<"
    ret_lyx=$$? ;\
    if [ "$$ret_lyx" != "0" ]; then \
      [ -f "$*.pdf" ] && rm "$*.pdf" ;\
    fi ;\
    exit $$ret_lyx
```

To test it out, put the above in a file "Makefile" and put that in a directory with a file "abc.lyx" and run "make". The below output gives an idea of how it works:

```
$ ls
abc.lyx  Makefile
$ make
lyx -e pdf4 "abc.lyx"
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./abc.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1

ret_lyx=$? ;\
if [ "$ret_lyx" != "0" ]; then \
  [ -f "abc.pdf" ] && rm "abc.pdf" ;\
fi ;\
exit $ret_lyx
$ make
make: 'abc.pdf' is up to date.
$ touch abc.lyx 
$ make
lyx -e pdf4 "abc.lyx"
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./abc.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1

ret_lyx=$? ;\
if [ "$ret_lyx" != "0" ]; then \
  [ -f "abc.pdf" ] && rm "abc.pdf" ;\
fi ;\
exit $ret_lyx
$
```

Comment: pretty sure this will not work? `make` will exit if the `lyx` command fails and the if check will never run or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought it would continue.